# Why do all components get rendered twice?

Tags: reactjs, components, lifecycle

I'm trying to learn lifecycles in react but something like this drives me nuts, why all components get rendered twice even when i call them once?

[image]

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    console.log("constructor");
    this.state = {
      name: "Alex",
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("componentDidMount");
    console.log("------------------");
  }
  render() {
    console.log("render");
    return <>Hello World</>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you're using react 18 and strictmode, react mounts everything twice in development as a means to detect bad lifecycle methods. It's covered in the docs.

Comment: @super thanks for your answer and time , but what should i do then ?

Answer (score 1):

in your main or index file, you might have this:[image]

That's the way of react to simply test your components, it will make a re-render looking for bugs, allows react to secure your application and identify the correct use of hooks and lifecycles.

You can also put StricMode like a Fragment in other components (cuz it won't render anything than the children), you can put out from your main file, but is not recommended. It wont do anything in production because if you run **npm run build** the strict mode disappear.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are using latest **React** **18** build.
Starting from this version framework will render all components twice in *development* mode.
To make sure that this is the case, please refer to your `package.json` file, `dependencies:{}` section. If it has something like this, then you on the right path to get rid of the double rendering.

```
dependencies:{
    ...
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    ...
}
```

All you have to do is to locate the `<React.StrictMode>` component and remove it from your source code.
It will fix your problem.

Please note that by removing Strict Mode you`re also removing some necessary check-ups that may help you to improve your code.
You can read more about it in the official React docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper